# Easiest way to get started with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, elastic-map-reduce

I was looking for the simplest way(s) to submit a MapReduce job.

I am looking for a platform similar in complexity (or simplicity) such a Heroku (is to Ruby) or picloud.com is to map.

The idea is where a beginner can submit a MapReduce job without having to deal with the complexities of setting up a Hadoop Cluster. Elastic Map Reduce comes close but the start up times to set up the instances is a big turn off.

So basically I was looking for someone who had done the picloud equivalent of MapReduce.

I also read the following answers but didn't find what I was looking for: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418632/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-started-with-hadoop-on-ec2-preferably-mapr) and [this one](http://answers.mapr.com/questions/2257/what-is-the-easiest-way-for-a-hadoop-newbie-to-get-started-with-mapr-on-one-ec2-box)

Thanks.

Comment: MapReduce jobs run on a Hadoop cluster, so you would need a set of machines with Hadoop installed. So, the first question that comes to mind is 1) do you have the hardware in-house to set up your own cluster, or 2) are you looking for "cloud" alternatives where you pay-per-instance depending on your usage? Sounds like you want to go with option 2. There is a start up cost of setting up a cluster with hadoop installed and you would face that with any vendor you go with if you spin them up on demand. If you want to keep the instances around, the start up time is irrelevant in the long run.

Comment: A 10 line whirr config can install a feature rich cluster within minutes. Another alternative is to download a preconfigured VM to which you can submit your job. It is not clear what you want to do with this cluster. POC? Production environment? Cloud or non cloud. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two good starter resources:

Using Amazon Elastic Mapreduce: http://aws.amazon.com/aws-training/elasticmapreduce/

Using the Cloudera CDH solution (more involved and relies on Hive instead of actual MapReduce jobs): http://www.infoq.com/articles/BigDataBlueprint

EDIT: If you aren't fond of Elastic MapReduce, you might want to give Sears MetaScale a try (I haven't tried it): http://www.metascale.com/services/big-data